# Función recursiva PHP duplicando valores

Tags: php

Tengo esta función que intenta duplicar el número actual, así hasta el infinito o se acabe la memoria.

```
$c = 1;
function exp( $n ){

  if( $n > 65000 ){
    return $n;
  }

  else{
    $r = $n * 2;
    echo $c . '.- ' . $r . '<br>';
    $c++;
    return exp( $r );
  }
}

echo exp( 1 );
```

yo espero esta salida

```
1.- 2
2.- 4
3.- 8
4.- 16
n.- n
```

Me ocurre este problema:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare exp() in FakePath on line 9
```

No entiendo que intento o PHP intenta re declarar.
Bienvenida toda ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`exp`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.exp.php) es una función de PHP, en tu código estás intentando redeclararla y el interprete no te lo permite por eso lanza ese error, puedes hacer una [sobrecarga](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.override-function.php) de esa función sí deseas utilizar esa palabra, o cambiar el nombre de tu función a lo que quieras, `exponente` por ejemplo.
También `$c` debe estar dentro de la función, si no te marcará un error de variable indefinida

```
function exponente( $n ){
  $c = 1;

  if( $n > 50 ){
    return $n;
  }

  else{
    $r = $n * 2;
    echo $c . '.- ' . $r . '<br>';
    $c++;
    return exponente( $r );
  }
}

echo exponente( 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que intentas no se puede hacer, una función recursiva necesita un caso base para evitar, precisamente, caer en un bucle infinito, como en tu caso no existe, el interprete te da ese error.

Ejemplo:

```
function factorial($v) 
{
    if ($v === 0) 
        return 1;
    else
        return $v * factorial($v-1);
}
print factorial(4);
```

Tu ejemplo funcionando

```
$c = 1;
function expon( $n ){
global $c;

  if( $n > 65000 ){
    return $n;
  }

  else{
    $r = $n * 2;
    echo $c . '.- ' . $r . '<br>';
    $c++;
    return expon( $r );
  }
}

echo expon( 1 );
```

También necesitas añadir una declaración **global**, para poder acceder a $c, desde dentro de tu función.

Comment: Ya modifiqué el código, le puse un alto en cierto número, pero me sigue lanzando el mismo error.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el nombre de la función, porque coincide, además que exp es una función que ya existe en php.

Comment: Claro, por eso es recursivo, quiero que se ejecute de nuevo. Es obvio que ya existe. :S

Comment: Pero ocurre un problema: ya existe una función en php que se llama exp, y en el interior de tu función, se llama a esta en vez de a tu "exp". Por eso da el error de la redeclaración.

Comment: $c = 1;
function expon( $n ){
global $c;
  if( $n > 65000 ){
    return $n;
  }

  else{
    $r = $n * 2;
    echo $c . '.- ' . $r . '<br>';
    $c++;
    return expon( $r );
  }
}

echo expon( 1 );